# How to find and make an invisible folder visible in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

My OS is Windows XP, and my problem is that I have an invisible folder.

That folder does not contain system files, it's on D:\ drive.

In the folder with music, I have subfolders for every singer/group, and when I try to make a new folder, it says that I already have folder with that name. I don't, so it must be an invisible one.

How do I make this folder visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to go to Start->Settings->Control Panel->Folder Options->View->Advanced Settings. Tick ‘Show hidden files and folders’ and untick ‘Hide protected operating system files’ (and confirm the annoying nag-o-box).

Now you should be able to see all files in Explorer. If you still don't see the folder, there could be a filesystem problem. Would be worth running the Error Checker over the drive in question.

Comment: I did what you said, and found two "things", that used to be two folders. Thay are 7 and 8 KB, but I can't delete them, it says "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable". Is there any way to delete them?

Comment: Try the Error Checker: right-click on the drive with the problem, choose Properties->Tools->Error Checker.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following

Open up a command window by typing cmd in the Run dialog (Start->Run). Then type the following

```
d:
cd \
attrib -r -a -s -h /s /d d:\
```

Comment: Though bear in mind that if there are a lot of files and folders in D: that this could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate there in a command prompt:

```
d:
cd [music folder]
attrib -H [name of folder] /D /S
```

This should make the folder visible once more. Try -S as well, if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things towards confirming existence of that folder.

1. From `cmd.exe` shell: change to parent folder and try to enter the folder in question

   - View the parent folder in **explorer** and change the view to show hidden and system files

Answer (score 0):

Being Windows XP, you can display hidden files and folders from the Tools > Folder Options > View menu in Windows Explorer.